# 3d touch on single photo. iOS, Swift

Tags: ios, 3dtouch

Can I add 3d touch to a single photo that is not in a collection view or a table view. everything i seem to see on it uses a collection view.

I have a single picture that shows on a view with information but the picture is a small square I have it so that I can tap the photo and it opens in a view controller but i wanted to add peek to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, all you need to do is conform to `UIViewControllerPreviewingDelegate`. When a deep press is registered the

```
func previewingContext(_ previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing, viewControllerForLocation location: CGPoint) -> UIViewController?
```

method will be called. If you return a non-nil view controller a peek and pop interaction will be initiated.

For example, here `ViewController` as a small centered image view. When the view is 3D touched we can check to see if the location is inside the image view. If so, we can preview the next view controller:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if traitCollection.forceTouchCapability == .available
        {
            registerForPreviewing(with: self, sourceView: view)
        }
        else
        {
            print("3D Touch Not Available")
        }
    }

}

extension ViewController: UIViewControllerPreviewingDelegate
{
    func previewingContext(_ previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing, viewControllerForLocation location: CGPoint) -> UIViewController?
    {
        let convertedLocation = view.convert(location, to: imagePhoto)
        if imagePhoto.bounds.contains(convertedLocation)
        {
            // Init the peek view controller, set relevant properties, and return it
            let otherViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "\(OtherViewController.self)") as? OtherViewController
            otherViewController?.image = imageView.image
            previewingContext.sourceRect = imageView.frame
            return otherViewController
        }
        else
        {
            return nil
        }
    }

    func previewingContext(_ previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing, commit viewControllerToCommit: UIViewController)
    {
        // Present or push the view controller
        present(viewControllerToCommit, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Where `OtherViewController` is a view controller with an image view that takes up the entire view.

Which gives a result of:

[image]

Comment: Thank you fro you Reply and time on this @beyowulf.. Ive tried to implement this, but how would this look if my mage was called imagePhoto.

Comment: `imagePhoto` is the name of your `UIImageView`? If `imagePhoto` is a subview of `view`, then you can say `if imagePhoto.frame.contains(location) { // Create the next view controller and pass the image on  }else { return nil; }`

Comment: a view in a view that has the image photo I am clicking. I have already set a gesture on it so I can click it and it will go to a new controller to show the image all that works fine.

Comment: guard let imageView = self.view.subviews.first(where: { _ in imagePhoto.frame.contains(location) }) as? UIImageView else { return nil }    This is what it changes it to

Comment: Yes thank you for this @beyowulf. This worked great for me instead of present, I used show and I named the view. to my second view that held my picture. but other than that it worked perfectly. Thanks you again, I appreciate your time and expertise on this....